# Ruby parsing for Notepad++ Function List panel

Tags: ruby, notepad++

As of version 6.4, Notepad++ now includes a Function List panel in the core application. What needs to be added to the functionList.xml to get it to correctly parse the functions out of a Ruby file?

Comment: That's for the old plugin. The functionality was added to the core Notepad++ distribution and uses a completely different syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a work-in-progress on Gist:
https://gist.github.com/monban/6133403

It reads functions, but does not correctly parse classes / modules. Please feel free to fork and improve.